# Illustrate standard deviation in histogram

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

Consider the following simple example:

```r
# E. Musk in Grunheide 
set.seed(22032022) 

# generate random numbers 
randomNumbers <- rnorm(n = 1000, mean = 10, sd = 10)

# empirical sd 
sd(randomNumbers)
#> [1] 10.34369

# histogram 
hist(randomNumbers, probability = TRUE, main = "", breaks = 50)

# just for illusatration purpose 
###
# empirical density 
lines(density(randomNumbers), col = 'black', lwd = 2)
# theortical density 
curve(dnorm(x, mean = 10, sd = 10), col = "blue", lwd = 2, add = TRUE)
###
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Question:**
Is there a nice way to illustrate the empirical standard deviation (sd) in the histogram by colour?
E.g. representing the inner bars by a different color, or indicating the range of the sd by an interval, i.e., [mean +/- sd], on the x-axis?

Note, if `ggplot2` provides an easy solution, suggesting this would be also much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is similar `ggplot` solution to Benson's answer, except we precompute the histogram and use `geom_col`, so that we don't get any of the unwelcome stacking at the sd boundary:

```r
# E. Musk in Grunheide 
set.seed(22032022) 

# generate random numbers 
randomNumbers <- rnorm(n=1000, mean=10, sd=10)

h <- hist(randomNumbers, breaks = 50, plot = FALSE)

lower <- mean(randomNumbers) - sd(randomNumbers)
upper <- mean(randomNumbers) + sd(randomNumbers)

df <- data.frame(x = h$mids, y = h$density, 
                 fill = h$mids > lower & h$mids < upper)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(x, y, fill = fill), width = 1, color = 'black') +
  geom_density(data = data.frame(x = randomNumbers), 
               aes(x = x, color = 'Actual density'),
               key_glyph = 'path') +
  geom_function(fun = function(x) {
    dnorm(x, mean = mean(randomNumbers), sd = sd(randomNumbers)) },
    aes(color = 'theoretical density')) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c(`TRUE` = '#FF374A', 'FALSE' = 'gray'), 
                    name = 'within 1 SD') +
  scale_color_manual(values = c('black', 'blue'), name = 'Density lines') +
  labs(x = 'Value of random number', y = 'Density') +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Here is a `ggplot` solution. First calculate `mean` and `sd`, and save the values in different vectors. Then use an `ifelse` statement to categorise the values into "Within range" and "Outside range", `fill` them with different colours.

Blue line represents the normal distribution stated in your question, and black line represents the density graph of the histogram we're plotting.

```r
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(22032022) 

# generate random numbers 
randomNumbers <- rnorm(n=1000, mean=10, sd=10)

randomNumbers_mean <- mean(randomNumbers)
randomNumbers_sd <- sd(randomNumbers)

ggplot(data.frame(randomNumbers = randomNumbers), aes(randomNumbers)) +
  geom_histogram(aes(
    fill = ifelse(
      randomNumbers > randomNumbers_mean + randomNumbers_sd |
        randomNumbers < randomNumbers_mean - randomNumbers_sd,
      "Outside range",
      "Within range"
    )
  ), 
  binwidth = 1, col = "gray") +
  geom_density(aes(y = ..count..)) + 
  stat_function(fun = function(x) dnorm(x, mean = 10, sd = 10) * 1000,
                color = "blue") +
  labs(fill = "Data")
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-03-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

```r
data.frame(rand = randomNumbers,
           cut = {
             sd <- sd(randomNumbers)
             mn <- mean(randomNumbers)
             cut(randomNumbers, c(-Inf, mn -sd, mn +sd, Inf))
           }) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = rand, fill = cut ) ) +
  geom_histogram()
```

[image]